# How to get sum of two different table when using union with laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

my code look like this

```
 $docManual = DB::table('document_manuals')
                    ->whereYear('document_manuals.created_at', $monthYear)
                    ->whereMonth('document_manuals.created_at', '=', $monthly)
                    ->select('document_manuals.format_type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->groupBy('document_manuals.format_type');
                    

                $format = DB::table('documents')
                    ->whereYear('documents.created_at', $monthYear)
                    ->whereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', $monthly)
                    ->select('.documents.format_type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->groupBy('documents.format_type')
                    ->unionAll($docManual)
                    ->get();
```

output

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1676 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#1679 ▼
      +"format_type": "pdf"
      +"total": 1
    }
    1 => {#1682 ▼
      +"format_type": "ppt"
      +"total": 1
    }
    2 => {#1678 ▼
      +"format_type": "doc"
      +"total": 1
    }
    3 => {#1684 ▼
      +"format_type": "pdf"
      +"total": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make the output look like this

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1676 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#1679 ▼
      +"format_type": "pdf"
      +"total": 3
    }
    1 => {#1682 ▼
      +"format_type": "ppt"
      +"total": 1
    }
    2 => {#1678 ▼
      +"format_type": "doc"
      +"total": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Question is how to combine and sum the item with two table using UNION ? to make it more clear, i have two table and the data is :

```
first table : document_manuals
pdf : 1

second table : documents
pdf : 2
ppt : 1
doc : 1
```

So anyone know how to combine them so that the output look like i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $data = collect([
            ['format_type' => 'pdf', 'total' => 1],
            ['format_type' => 'ppt', 'total' => 1],
            ['format_type' => 'doc', 'total' => 1],
            ['format_type' => 'pdf', 'total' => 2],
        ]);
        $result = collect([]);
        $data->groupBy('format_type')->map(function ($item, $key) use ($result) {
            $result->push((object)['format_type' => $key, 'total' => $item->sum('total')]);
        });
        dd($result->toArray());
```